# Computation of $\omega$- limit set of the given system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'   \\
y'  
\end{bmatrix}
=F\begin{bmatrix}
x   \\
y  
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y(y^2+(x^2-1)^2)+x(1-x^2-y^2)   \\
-x(y^2+(x^2-1)^2)+y(1-x^2-y^2)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I need to calculate $\omega(p)$ $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}^2$. ($\omega(x) = \{y \in X: \text{there is}\ t_n \to +\infty\ \text{such that}\ \phi(t_n,x) \to y   \}$ )

My hint is: $<p, F(p)>$. I do not know how to do this, I found $$<p, F(p)>=||p||^2(1-||p||^2).$$

Any help would be great.

Comment: what is $\phi$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: The flow of the system (it's standard notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $p$ points in the radial direction, so the sign of the inner product $\langle p,F(p) \rangle$ tells you whether the vector $F(p)$ is pointing “outwards” or “inwards”. And from the expression you computed, it's clear that this depends on whether you're inside or outside the unit circle. Can you take it from there?

Comment: No, I am sorry. None of these info you provided is familiar to me.

Comment: @P.G: It's just linear algebra: the inner product tells you about the angle between the vectors, and in particular the sign of the inner product tells you if the angle is acute or obtuse. But never mind, try this instead: rewrite the system in polar coordinates, and then try to figure out what the equation for $dr/dt$ is telling you. (Actually, you don't even need to bother with deriving the equation for the angular varable, just focus on the radial variable $r$.) This is basically the same thing as the hint you were given, but it might be easier to understand it in that way.

Comment: I tried polar coordinates before write the question. I found $r'=r(1-r^2)$.  I do not know what I am looking for...

Comment: @P.G: OK, good start. Now what does $r(t)$ tend to as $t \to \infty$? You should be able to see this just from the 1-dimensional phase portrait for the equation $r'=r(1-r^2)$.

Comment: $r(t) \to  1$ (if we start in the first or second quadrant) and $r(t) \to  -1$ (if we start in the third or fourth quadrant)

Comment: Not quite. Note that $r$ is never negative (it's the distance from the point $(x,y)$ to the origin, after all). So unless you start at the origin (where $r=0$), you will have $r(t) \to 1$. In other words, you will approach the unit circle in the $xy$-plane. But here is where the problem seems to be getting a bit more complicated. There are two equilibria on the unit circle, namely $(x,y)=(\pm 1,0)$, and each trajectory (not starting at the origin) will converge to one of them, but it's not obvious to me how to determine exactly which trajectories that end up at which equilibrium.

Comment: Maybe it can be seen if you work out the equation for $d\theta/dt$, but I haven't tried it myself. Here's what the phase portrait looks like: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7By+%28y%5E2+%2B+%28x%5E2+-+1%29%5E2%29+%2B+x+%281+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%2C+-x+%28y%5E2+%2B+%28x%5E2+-+1%29%5E2%29+%2B+y+%281+-+x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29%7D%2Cx%3D-3..3%2Cy%3D-3..3

Comment: so all $\omega$-limit sets lies in the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, except for the origin (which forms the $\omega$-limit set for the origin (only)).